YOLOv10 custom training - import YOLO or YOLOv10?
I wish to apply a custom-training with YoloV10n on a dataset I have (I've been using YoloV8 until now), but I'm not sure wether to use/import YOLO or YOLOv10.
I've initially tried to use YOLOv10, and was able to complete successfully custom training and then inference. However I wasn't able to export the model to tflite due to inconsistency assertions. I then switched back to YOLO (starting from a pre-trained yolov10.pt model) and was able to export it for tflite. Moreover, the official documentation of Ultralytics do guide for using YOLO (and not YOLOv10) for YoloV10 training. On the other side RoboFlow tutorial does guide to use YOLOv10... 
Shall I use from ultralytics import YOLOv10 or from ultralytics import YOLO? Does it matter? Does same answer hold for both training, inference and export (tflite, etc.)?

As stated in the up-to-date Ultralytics documentation it will be correct to use from ultralytics import YOLO. Here are some usage examples:
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load YOLOv10n model from scratch
model = YOLO("yolov10n.yaml")

# Load a pre-trained YOLOv10n model
model = YOLO("yolov10n.pt")

# Train the model
model.train(data="coco8.yaml", epochs=100, imgsz=640)

# Perform object detection on an image
results = model("image.jpg")

# Export the model to NCNN format
model.export(format="ncnn")  # creates 'yolov10n_ncnn_model'

As for the recommendation to use the YOLOv10 module, it comes from the earlier times when this model wasn't fully integrated into Ultralytics (approximately May 2024). For example, in this Roboflow article from May 24, it is proposed to install the Official PyTorch implementation of YOLOv10 first and then use it with Ultralytics, which is excessive for now and may lead to the unwanted behavior like export issues. If you are using Ultralytics, follow the official tutorials and operate with v10 as you do with the v8 model.

Got it, thank you!
